# ASP.NET Core 2.0 APIs and IdentityServer4 Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

We are developing APIs in ASP.NET Core 2.0 for external partners. For example, insurance domain having various products like Motor, Travel, Home etc.

Now, We are configured IdentityServer4 for authentication type "ResourseOwnerPassword" and authorization for APIs as -

Service List :

1. https://domain:port/Motor/api/v1/CalculatePremium
2. https://domain:port/Motor/api/v1/ProposalSync
3. https://domain:port/Motor/api/v1/InstaProposalSync
4. https://domain:port/Travel/api/v1/CalculatePremium
5. https://domain:port/Travel/api/v1/ProposalSync

Authorization @API :

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AuthPolicy", builder =>
        {
          builder.RequireScope("MotorApi","TravelApi","PaymentApi");
        });
    });
```

Question : 
How we authorize specify service with required scope , means 
Partner-A can access only "Motor/api/v1/CalculatePremium", not others product service.

Partner-B can access only travel services , not other product service.

Please assist correct approach to achieve this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can assign roles to the user when they login and use a middleware like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {

    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

        if (context.Request.Path == "/Motor/api/v1/CalculatePremium"
                    && !context.User.IsInRole("Partner-A"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        else await next();
    }
    else await next();

});
```

There are cleaner ways to set up a middleware by making it a separate class if you would like.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is definitely helpful. However, currently we have almost 70+ services across all product and 5+ Partners. More additional partners will come or may be need to revoke access in future. So, configuration must be ad-hoc/dynamic from maintainability point of view. Please suggest how can we maintain this authorization configuration with identityserver in DB or any resource file.